# Ksqldb Data Enrichment for nested array

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I learn ksqldb Data Enrichment and there was a question: Can ksqldb enrich nested array?

**ktable users:**

```
 {
      "userId": "1",
      "displayname": "Fred",
      "Tags": [2,5,6,7]
    },
    {
      "userId": "2",
      "displayname": "Ben",
      "Tags": [5,1,5,2]
    },
```

**Tags ktable:**

```
{
   tagid: 2,
   Name: "firstag"
},
{
   tagid: 5,
   Name: "nexttag"
}
```

expected result how it do mongodb with 'lookup'
**Result enrich:**

```
{
   "userId": "1",
   "displayname": "Fred",
   "Tags": [
        {
          tagid: 2,
          Name: "firstag"
        },
        {
          tagid: 5,
          Name: "nexttag"
        }
    ]
}
```